# How to prevent a Screen Overlay attack in Flutter or forbid another app to run over the original app

Tags: flutter, screenshot, screen-recording

Flutter masters!

I am designing an app that has sensitive information in it. I want to prevent a screen overlay attack - i.e. another app that mimics my app and instead of in my TextField to enter text into the bad app's TextField.

Is there a way to detect that another app is running on top of my app?

Also - how can I forbid taking screenshots and recording screen video when using the app?

Regards!

Comment: does this help [Prevent Screenshot and Video Recording in Flutter](https://mrgulshanyadav.medium.com/prevent-screenshot-and-video-recording-in-flutter-93839325d66c)